# undefined returned for currentView object in Backbone.Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I am testing how a layout can listen to its subviews's custom events.

I created a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/olivierntk/Fj4fr/40/) where I have a layout, 2 regions and I instantiated 2 ItemViews and showed them in the layout's regions. The fiddle is in CoffeeScript.

```
<div id="region"></div>
<script id="layout-tmpl" type="text/_">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="content2"></div>    
</script>

<script id="item-tmpl" type="text/_">
    <form>
        <label>Firstname:</lable>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<%= firstname %>" />
        <input type="button" value="Save" id="save" />
    </form>    
</script>
```

And the CoffeeScript is:

```
SimpleLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend 
    template: '#layout-tmpl' 
    regions:
        main: '#content'
        other: '#content2'
    initialize: () ->
        console.log @
    onShow: () ->
        _.each @.regionManagers, (region, name, something) =>
            console.log region.currentView
            # @.bindTo region.currentView, "custom:event", @callback           
    callback: () ->
        alert "HELL YEAH"

SimpleItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
    template: "#item-tmpl"
    events:
        'click #save': 'save'
    save: (evt) ->             
        evt.preventDefault()
        @.trigger "custom:event"

region = new Backbone.Marionette.Region el: "#region"    
layout = new SimpleLayout() 
region.show layout
layout.main.show new SimpleItemView model: (new Backbone.Model firstname: "Olivier")
layout.other.show new SimpleItemView model: (new Backbone.Model firstname: "Travis")
```

I want the layout to listen to the ItemViews's custom events. In the onShow, I am looping through the region managers and trying to access the currentView object but it returns undefined.

If I attach the same event handlers outside of the SimpleLayout class and after I show the itemviews, then the layout handlers the custom events properly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is that the views aren't actually ready when the layout's `onShow` gets called:

```
layout = new SimpleLayout() 

region.show layout
```

// onShow called here, no views to bind to, since they haven't been created yet

```
layout.main.show new SimpleItemView model: (new Backbone.Model firstname: "Olivier")
layout.other.show new SimpleItemView model: (new Backbone.Model firstname: "Travis") 

// now the views are ready, they can be bound to
_.each layout.regionManagers, (region, name) =>
    console.log region.currentView
    region.currentView.bindTo region.currentView, "custom:event", () ->
        alert "HELL YEAH"
```

[Here's a forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6TYL/3/) that shows the `custom:event` getting triggered.

Comment: Yes, I had it working exactly the same way, and it is true that in my class definition, when the onShow is called on the layout, there aren't views in the region. It is obvious to me now (wasn't before :)). However, I wanted a place in the Layout class where I could bind to the views, instead of calling this piece of code after I add the subviews. See what I mean?